# How to load/configure a multi-pom file project in Eclipse Mars

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, eclipse-mars

I am using Eclipse Mars and am migrating a legacy app to maven and am having miserable time with one module in particular.  The way the Ant script worked is that it built 3 or 4 artifacts from the same code base.

- secure-EJB.jar (some subset of classes)
- secure-EJB-client.jar (client EJB)
- unsecure-EJB.jar (another subset of classes)
- library.jar (regular java library with the bulk of classes, apart from the EJB beans/facades)

At first I tried to get Maven to build everything via a single pom, but that was just a recipe for disaster (and broke just about every maven convention I know), so I abandoned the concept altogether.

Instead, I ended up with 4 poms - each building to a separate target/ folder:

1. pom.xml (parent pom, defines all the dependencies required for the
   build, and includes the 3 next poms as modules)
2. pom-ejb-secure.xml (inherits pom.xml)
3. pom-ejb-unsecure.xml (inherits pom.xml)
4. pom-jar.xml (inherits pom.xml)

pom.xml (snippet):

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>ejb-pom</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.myc</groupId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>


<modules>
    <module>pom-securedEjb.xml</module>
    <module>pom-unsecuredEjb.xml</module>
    <module>pom-jar.xml</module>
</modules>

<properties>
    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
</properties>

<build>
   <directory>${project.basedir}/target/${project.artifactId}</directory>
     ...
     ... 
</build>
```

From a command line build (ex: mvn clean deploy), everything works properly, and as expected.  All artifacts are independently built and deployed, at the cost of recompiling the classes for each pom.

However, I have no idea how to load/configure this in Eclipse/m2e such that it sees the different artifacts produced, and more importantly is able to resolve against them when referenced in other open projects (Enable Workspace Resolution).

When I import the maven project, it just "loads" the parent pom.xml and does not recognize that there are modules that need to be loaded/resolved as well.

Is there anything I can do about this?  Is there anyway to configure Eclipse to view multiple poms for a single project?

Comment: Use better names like `secure-ejb` and name the folders exactly like it...What do you mean by `each building to a separate target/ folder`....?

Comment: @khmarbaise - I added my <directory> defn to the parent pom so you understand what I mean.  Each module will run the build section in its own target/${artifactId} folder so that one build doesn't step on the other build.  I can't separate the code into 3 separate modules - much too great a refactoring job.